# vk api get wall comments

Tags: vkontakte-api

```
<?php
$query = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?owner_id=55692777&post_id=3335118");
$query = json_decode($query);
var_dump($query);
?>
```

Возвращает

```
Access denied: post was not found check post_id param
```

Где допустил ошибку? Всем спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в значении *owner_id*: юзера с [id55692777](https://vk.com/id55692777) не существует.

Возможно, вас интересует не юзер, а *сообщество* с таким id. В этом случае, в метод [`wall.getComments()`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.getComments) надо передавать его id со знаком минус:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?owner_id=-55692777&post_id=3335118&v=5.58
```

[Так](https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?owner_id=-55692777&post_id=3335118&v=5.58) все работает.

Также не забывайте передавать версию API в параметре `v`, поскольку в будущем запросы без указанных версий [будут возвращать ошибку](https://vk.com/wall-1_340400).

Comment: @terron Если вам есть что добавить оформите другим ответом а не правками  текущего...

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тут все просто, у юзера на стене нет поста с таким *post_id*, проверяйте стену. И не забывайте передавать *access_token* и *v* (версия API).