# VK API ошибка метода wall.createComment Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api

Писали бота по документации VK-IO. Бот работал как надо. После обновления библиотеки начали вылезать ошибки, поправили все согласно новой документации. Однако `vk.api.wall.createComment` не отрабатывает. Как можно поправить ошибку?

```
let { VK, resolveResource } = require('vk-io');
let sample = (array) => array[Math.round((array.length - 1) * Math.random())];

let { TOKEN, GROUPS, PHRASES, MILLISECONDS, COMMENT_NUM, COMMENT_TIMEOUT } = require('./config');

let vk = new VK({
  token: TOKEN,
});

console.log('> Бот запущен.');

let commented = [];
let ids = [];

(async () => {
  ids = await Promise.all(GROUPS.map(async (link) => {
  let res = await resolveResource({api: vk.api, resource: link});
    if (!res || res.type !== 'group') throw new Error('Ссылка должна вести на группу');
    return -res.id;
  }));

  setInterval(async () => {
      
    let { items } = await vk.api.newsfeed.get({ filters: 'post', count: 1 });
   let post = items[0];
   
    if (!ids.includes(post.source_id) || commented.includes(post.post_id)) return;
    commented.push(post.post_id);
    
        try { 
      //for (let i = 0; i < COMMENT_NUM; i++) {
        // let message = sample(PHRASES);
        // await vk.api.wall.createComment({ owner_id: post.source_id, post_id: post.post_id, message });
        // console.log(`> Был оставлен комментарий <<${message}>>`);
        // setTimeout(() => {}, COMMENT_TIMEOUT);
      // } 
      let message = sample(PHRASES);
      console.log(post.source_id, post.post_id, message)
        vk.api.wall.createComment({ owner_id: post.source_id, post_id: post.post_id, message });
        console.log('сообщение '+message)

        
    } catch (e) { 
    
      let errors = {
        212: 'Access to post comments denied',
        213: 'Нет доступа к комментированию записи (возможно, комментарии были закрыты)',
        222: 'Запрещённые гиперссылки',
        223: 'Превышен лимит комментариев на стене',
      };

      let error = errors[e.code] || 'Неизвестная ошибка';

      throw new Error(error);
    }
  
  }, MILLISECONDS);
})();
```

Ошибки:

```
(node:21352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: APIError: Code №29 - Rate limit reached
at SequentialWorker.execute (C:\Users\User\node_modules\vk-io\lib\index.js:1584:39)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:21352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21352) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: неужели по `Code №29 - Rate limit reached` ничего не гуглится?

Comment: Эта ошибка появилась видимо после тестов. Сам факт, что до превышения лимита запросов сообщение не уходило. Через форму в документации все прекрасно отрабатывало

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453780